# Generate xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, hashmap

I want to generate xml file. The input from user is, xml template without values. I'm willing to use xslt here but, not having idea about how utilize that. I clearly picturize my idea. Please suggest your ideas.
xml template:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <details>
            <name/>
            <age/>
        </details>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Java Code:

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("name","xxx");
map.put("age","27");
```

xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:map="xalan://java.util.Map" extension-element-prefixes="map">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="map" />
    <xsl:template match="/class">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <details>
                    <name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="map:get($map,(String)$name)" />
                    </name>
                    <age>
                        <xsl:value-of select="map:get($map,(String)$age)" />
                    </age>
                </details>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above code is only sample and it won't execute perfectly. So, Please comment if you have full code especially the value inserted into xslt from hashmap and using xml template to brought up the same xml with values in output.

Comment: So why do you need the Java HashMap? Can't you simply yse `<xsl:param name="name"/>` and `<name><xsl:value-of select="$name"/></name>`?

Comment: user giving only xml template. The values of the xml fields are retrieved from db and stored in hashmap. Now set the values in xml using xslt.

Comment: I don't quite understand what benefits are you reaping from using XSLT here. Loading the user inputted document with JDOM 2, and looking for elements of the same name as your Map keys and setting their content when found, sound much easier and closer to what the technologies are designed for.